How do I improve my efficiency for the Hamiltonian Path problem?
I've been trying to solve this problem:
Let us consider the problem of calculating the number of paths in an n×n grid from the upper-left corner to the lower-right corner such that the path visits each square exactly once. For example, in a 7 × 7 grid, there are 111712 such paths.
I have a program that I think works, but I have been trying to follow some optimisation steps such as always moving up for the first step and then multiplying the paths by 2 because of symmetry and also returning if the final square is reached without going through all the squares.
I've been trying to implement this:  if the path cannot continue forward but can turn either left or right, the grid splits into two parts that both contain unvisited squares and so cannot be solved, so the function should stop searching this path.
The code I have written so far is below, but I have checked through cout statements and in the is_grid_splitting function true is never being returned and I am not sure why?
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const int n = 5;
vector<vector<int>> grid(n, vector<int>(n, 0));
int paths = 0;
vector<vector<bool>> visited(n, (vector<bool>(n, false)));
int last_turn;

bool is_valid(int x, int y) {
    return x >=0 && x < n && y >= 0 && y < n && !visited[x][y]; 
}

bool is_grid_splitting(int x, int y) {
    if (last_turn == 1) {
        if (is_valid(x, y+1) && visited[x][y+1]
        && is_valid(x-1, y) && !visited[x-1][y] 
        && is_valid(x+1, y) && !visited[x+1][y]) 
        {return true;}
    }

    if (last_turn == 2) {
        if (is_valid(x+1, y) && visited[x+1][y]
        && is_valid(x, y-1) && !visited[x][y-1]
        && is_valid(x, y+1) && !visited[x][y+1])
        {return true;}
    }

    if (last_turn == 3) {
        if (is_valid(x, y-1) && visited[x][y-1]
        && is_valid(x-1, y) && !visited[x-1][y]
        && is_valid(x+1, y) && !visited[x+1][y])
        {return true;}
    }

    if (last_turn == 4) {
        if (is_valid(x-1,y) && visited[x-1][y]
        && is_valid(x, y-1) && !visited[x][y-1]
        && is_valid(x, y+1) && !visited[x][y+1])
        {return true;}
    }

    return false;
}

void path(int x, int y, int count) {
    if (x == n-1 && y == n-1 && count == n * n) {paths++; return;}

    if (x == n-1 && y == n-1) {return;}
    
    if (!is_grid_splitting(x, y)) {
        visited[x][y] = true;

        if (is_valid(x, y+1)) {
            last_turn = 1;
            path(x, y+1, count + 1);
        }

        if (is_valid(x+1, y)) {
            last_turn = 2;
            path(x+1, y, count + 1);
        }

        if (is_valid(x, y-1)) {
            last_turn = 3;
            path(x, y-1, count + 1);
        }

        if (is_valid(x-1, y)) {
            last_turn = 4;
            path(x-1, y, count + 1);
        }

        visited[x][y] = false;
    } else {return;}   

}

    

int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    
    last_turn = 3;
    visited[0][0] = true;
    path(0, 1, 2);

    paths *= 2;
    cout << paths;
}


Your problem (that you should include as text instead of as a link to an image) is lacking a question. Your code seems to be counting the number of paths, is it what you are trying to do?

Yes, to count the number of unique paths that cover every square and get from one corner to the opposite. I will edit my question so it is clearer, thanks.

I'm sorry, but you fallen into the competition-trap. Such sites doesn't teach you the basics of anything, only bad habits, bad code, sometimes even invalid code, and pulling you into a cargo cult. If you want to learn the basics of programming or C++, and are serious about it, then please invest in some good books instead.

@hardmath: except it is NP-complete in the general case. In a mxn grid graph like the one in the question, if m or n are odd, then there will be a hamilton path from the top left to the bottom right nodes (existence is what the hamiltonian path problem is BTW, it is not about counting them). Anyway, this question looks it would be a better fit to https://math.stackexchange.com

@Atmo: Excellent points (I responded to the title without properly digesting the body of the Question).  Yes, Math SE is a good fit for such counting problems, but I'd encourage the OP to focus on explaining their algorithm if they wanted to ask there.  Possibly a divide and conquer approach would be an efficient counting method, but I don't know off the top of my head.

I'm suggesting Math SE in case a formula exist. There is no indication that OP has tried to find one and I have not managed to find it either. If it exists, it (or at worst, a simplified algorithm for this particular case) is more likely to be found there than here. The question is likely to come from a competition site, as was commented before, and I doubt the problem, including all its constraints, is complicated.

For odd size square grids these counts are the subject of OEIS A001184; even size squares have no Hamiltonian paths from corner to corner by a checkerboard argument.  If there were a known closed formula, I'm sure it would be mentioned there.  Math Overflow also has some closely related posts.

@hardmath Not sure if we can have a sync'ed conversation but it would be my pleasure to join, yes

@Atmo: I made us a public chatroom, Counting Hamiltonian walks on a square grid.

ABC: 20 reputation are needed to talk in chat.  I've upvoted this Question, which gets you half way there.
